# Year Interval in Combo Box

Tags: php, mysql, forms, combobox

```
<select name="year" >
    <option value="0000"<?php echo $year == '0000' ? 'selected="selected"' : ''; ?>>Year:</option>

<?php
for($i=date('Y'); $i>1899; $i--) {
    $selected = '';
    if ($year == $i) $selected = ' selected="selected"';
    print('<option value="'.$i.'"'.$selected.'>'.$i.'</option>'."\n");
}
?>

</select>
```

This is my code for the user to choose the year he entered in a combobox, but i wanted to make a 2  year interval like **2000-2002** and etc until the present year. Help me how? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `$i=$i-2` instead of `$i--`.

Something like that:

```
<select name="year" >
    <option value="0000"<?php echo $year == '0000' ? 'selected="selected"' : ''; ?>>Year:</option>

   <?php
for($i=date('Y'); $i>1899; $i=$i-2) {
    $selected = '';
    $year2 = $i-2;
    if ($year == $i) $selected = ' selected="selected"';
    print('<option value="'.$year2. " " . $i .'" '.$selected.'> '.$year2.' '.$i.'</option>'."\n");
}
?>

</select>
```

Comment: I tried this but it gives me 
**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''-'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)** @Michael Lane

Comment: One of the quote was at the wrong place, you can make a new try, I correct it. (I haven't test it)

Comment: I tested now it's supposed to be okay